# Obtain all available subkeys of a translation dictionary key in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Having the code

```
// umbraco.cms.businesslogic.language.Language
static string GetUmbracoDictionaryValueOrNull(string key, Language lang)
{
    try
    {
        if (Dictionary.DictionaryItem.hasKey(key))
            return new Dictionary.DictionaryItem(key).Value(lang.id);
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it possible, having a key, say "`ui.mySelect`" to obtain all available/existing subkeys, say "`ui.mySelect.optionOne`", "`ui.mySelect.optionTwo`",... , "`ui.mySelect.optionLast`".

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
public static List<string> GetDictionarySubValues(string key)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary.DictionaryItem(key);
    if (dic == null || !dic.hasChildren) return new List<string>();

    return dic.Children
              .Select(c => c.Value())
              .ToList();
}
```